# JMS Connection constantly "session is closed" on our oracle queues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, oracle-aq

We are using spring boot to run our queue polling program.

The queue is being polled about every 2 mins, and every 2 mins the session is closed, then refreshed.

The connection is a shared connection from the external tomcat, this connection is shared with a dozen other applications.

```
    2018-11-20 11:59:21.263 WARN [serviceRequestAdapter.container-3] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'NPP.SERVICE_REQUEST' - 
      trying to recover. Cause: JMS-131: Session is closed
    2018-11-20 11:59:21.265 INFO [serviceRequestAdapter.container-3] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - 
      Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
    2018-11-20 12:01:21.781 WARN [serviceRequestAdapter.container-4] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'NPP.SERVICE_REQUEST' - 
      trying to recover. Cause: JMS-131: Session is closed
    2018-11-20 12:01:21.823 INFO [serviceRequestAdapter.container-4] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - 
      Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

This doesn't actually appear to be affecting functionality, as messages posted get consumed and processed.

**Is this actually a problem, if so how do I fix it?**

**If it isn't a problem how do I hide these messages without reducing my log level to error?**

our jms-context.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <int:message-history/>

    <int:channel id="jms-inbound"/>
    <int:channel id="voucher-create-inbound"/>
    <int:channel id="voucher-update-inbound"/>
    <int:channel id="default-inbound"/>

    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                                    connection-factory-type="QUEUE_CONNECTION"
                                    use-local-data-source-transaction="true"/>

    <int:recipient-list-router input-channel="jms-inbound" default-output-channel="default-inbound"
                               id="action-type-router">
        <int:recipient channel="voucher-create-inbound"
                       selector-expression="headers.actionType == 'CREATE VOUCHER'"/>
        <int:recipient channel="voucher-update-inbound"
                       selector-expression="headers.actionType == 'UPDATE VOUCHER'"/>
    </int:recipient-list-router>

    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
            id="serviceRequestAdapter"
            channel="jms-inbound"
            cache-level="3"
            connection-factory="connectionFactory"
            destination-name="${oracle.rqst-q-name}"/>

    <int:service-activator id="createVoucherActivator"
                           input-channel="voucher-create-inbound"
                           requires-reply="false"
                           method="onMessage">
        <beans:bean class="VoucherRequestConsumer"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:service-activator id="updateVoucherActivator"
                           input-channel="voucher-update-inbound"
                           requires-reply="false"
                           method="onMessage">
        <beans:bean class="VoucherRequestConsumer"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <beans:bean id="defaultRequestConsumer"
                class="DefaultRequestConsumer"/>
    <int:service-activator id="defaultActivator"
                           input-channel="default-inbound"
                           requires-reply="false"
                           ref="defaultRequestConsumer"
                           method="onMessage">
    </int:service-activator>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bit puzzled . . . what are you asking? I mean I don't see a question.
Are you just looking for confirmation that it's ok?

In any event, consider this doc - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html, specifically *Section 4.3 Configuring the Connection Factory to use the same local transaction as your data access code.* which specifically talks about implications on JMS Session when `use-local-data-source-transaction` is set to `true`.

Comment: Ok, gone through that and I believe I have ticked all of their boxes.